# Issue with Block Release in Airtable

Tags: airtable

I am currently facing an issue while trying to release an extension created in Airtable using the "Block Release" command. I have encountered the following error:
Error: ❌ The block could not be found. Make sure your API key is correct and that you have access to the block.
Code: airtableApiBlockNotFound

I have verified that the blockId and baseId in the remote.json file are correct. Despite this, I am unable to proceed with the release. I believe I have the necessary access permissions, and my API key is accurate.
Please help me with a solution